# Terminal Server 2008 - Certain users experience slow load times for certain processes

Tags: terminal, process

I'm tearing my hair out here. Please can someone assist me. I have users on a terminal server and they all use the same programs - Office and an Accounting package, yet certain processes are slower to load for userB & userC, while userA gets an immediate prompt from the process. It takes userB/C 30s for the prompt to appear. UserA gets the prompt in 1 or 2 seconds.

I have opened the Task Manager and watched the processes tab to see what the system is doing when the users press a button to, lets say, action an invoice to be created and sent via email. UserA sees the process Example.exe load up to 10k memory and the prompt appears, virtually instantaneously. UserB & C, for the same process, see the memory amount hover around 3k for 20s and then it shoots to 10k and the prompt appears.

The users have the same rights to the folder and files holding the Accounting software. Is there anything I can check to what is causing this and how I can fix it?

Thanks

---

I've resolved the problem. Using Process Monitor as suggested by pk. below, I found that when the process was started it tries to contact a bunch of remote sites. I enabled the 'Use a Proxy' setting in Internet Options and doing that made the process start instantly.

Thanks for the help guys.

Not sure how I can mark this solved?

Comment: Why and how would permissions affect the speed at which the prompt loads? Is the problem evident with other programs (you mentioned Office and an accounting package)? What are the symptoms in Office applications (Word, Excel, etc.)?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why permissions would affect it, but logged in as an account with Admin privileges I get the same experience as userA. This makes me suspect permissions. No, all other programs load fine. I am only experiencing this problem with the Accounting software and a few processes.

Comment: Is userA an admin? Does the problem only occur with functions that spawn email processes?

Comment: To mark this as resolved submit your answer as an answer and the Op will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it always the same users?  You might try replacing the user profiles of the users that are experiencing the delays.  It's possible there is some sort of corruption that would be resolved with a clean profile.  You could also use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see what exactly is going on behind the scenes when users are seeing delays.  You may a process hammering away unsucessfully at a simple operation that is then met with a timeout after 20 seconds or so.

Comment: I am going to create a new profile for the user to see of that helps. I have tested with my test account and experience the same results as userB/C. I'm wondering if it's a permissions problem somewhere along the line between the 3 users and my test account.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this earlier. When I first put the question up I thought typing in my details at the bottom of the post would register me :/

> Is userA an admin? Does the problem only occur with functions that spawn email processes?

UserA is not an admin. It belongs to the same groups as the other accounts.

edit

Okay, what I've done so far is login as userB and when the process starts (I've made it run as administrator) it opens instantly. When I remove the Run As Admin the process sits at 2k-3k memory usage for 30s before increasing and showing the prompt.